# access files in documents folder of application of iphone

Tags: iphone, filesystems

HEllo,

I have a situation here, I have an app , in this app I save  some files to documents folder. Now I want to export these files or view these files from mac.

Suggest some way for this.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll either need to set up a Bonjour connection over a local wifi network and figure out a protocol to move things that way, or upload the files from the device to a web service from which the user (or a desktop client app you create) can then download them. There is currently no way to piggy-back on the iTunes sync process, so the network's the only way to get things off of the device.

Comment: that will be quite a process for me......
well I am not a pretty much of Apple user, so I was wondering is there any thing like file manager or something in ipods or some COCOA API to do so......

Comment: No, there is no API to access the files stored on an iPhone from your Mac. You'll either have to follow Noah's suggestion or turn this into an app for jailbroken iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

you might also be able to use ftp. Run your ftp client on the iPhone and an ftp server on your mac.